# Need to strip off the comments in double quotes

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have test case which contains  string message  in double quotes and I want  to strip off data in double quotes. I used `awk` command to strip off comment section data but it doesn't work

```
awk '/^"/ { print }' full-case
```

sample input:

```
case('pr_ua_sfochi', "Response:answer(amount(2370.09,usd)", price).
```

Expected output:

```
case('pr_ua_sfochi',price).
```

Please advice.

awk '{gsub(/".*",/,"");print}' file.txt is working for above case but failed for following case.Here 2nd argument is in double quotes.

Actual case:

```
case('pr_ua_sfochi',"
Response:

answer(amount(2370.09,usd),[[01AUG06SFO UA CHI Q9.30 1085.58FUA2SFS UA SFO Q9.30 1085.58FUA2SFS NUC2189.76END ROE1.0 XT USD 180.33 ZPSFOCHI                                                           164.23US6.60ZP5.00AY XF4.50SFO4.5]],amount(2189.76,usd),amount(2189.76,usd),amount(180.33,usd),[[fua2sfs,fua2sfs]],amount(6.6,usd),amount(                                                          4.5,usd),amount(0.0,usd),amount(18.6,usd),lasttktdate([20061002]),lastdateafterres(200712282]),[[fic_ticketinfo(fare(fua2sfs),fic([]),nvb([                                                          ]),nva([]),tktiss([]),penalty([]),tktendorsement([]),tourinfo([]),infomsgs([])),fic_ticketinfo(fare(fua2sfs),fic([]),nvb([]),nva([]),tktiss                                                          ([]),penalty([]),tktendorsement([]),tourinfo([]),infomsgs([]))]],<>,<>,cat35(cat35info([])))
.
02/20/2006 17:05:10 Transaction 35 served by static.static.server1 (usclsefat002:7551) running E*Fare version $Name: build-2006-02-19-1900                                                           $",
price(pnr(
        user('atl','1y',<>,<>,dept(<>,'0005300'),<>,<>,<>),
        [
                passenger(adt,1,[ptconly(n)])
        ],
        [

segment(1,sfo,chi,'ua','<>','100',20140901,0800,f,20140901,2100,'737',res(20140628,1316),hk,pf2(n,[],[],n),<>,flags(no,no,no,no,no,no,no,no                                                          ,no)),

segment(2,chi,sfo,'ua','<>','101',20140906,1000,f,20140906,1400,'737',res(20140628,1316),hk,pf2(n,[],[],n),<>,flags(no,no,no,no,no,no,no,no                                                          ,no))
        ]),[
                rebook(n),
                ticket(20140301,131659),
                dbaccess(20140301,131659),
                platingcarrier('ua'),
                tax_exempt([]),
                trapparm("trap:ffil"),
                city(y)
        ])).
```

Comment: is the quoted string always in the second field?

Comment: No.It may vary commented section.

Comment: Apparently the string can contain an arbitrary number of newlines, a fact you did not consider important enought to mention right away...

Comment: Also, what about `trapparm("trap:ffil")`? Strip or keep?

Comment: We need to keep that.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with awk

```
awk '{sub(/".*",/,"");print}' filename
```

Comment: I think he is looking to remove text within quotes, including quotes and a comma following the quotes

Comment: Updated to also remove the trailing comma.

Comment: You use `gsub`, which implies you expect several double quoted strings. But then your regex is too greedy.

Comment: I updated the answer and sub'd gsub for sub. Thank you for pointing that out. I'm just used to using gsub all the time (a bad habit of mine)